# Keyword (by relevance) shows irrelevant string in result

Tags: google-ads-api, keyword-search

I am new to adwords keyword planner tool. I am using keyword planner tool for keyword research but i am getting Keyword (by relevance) result some thing odd. such as please see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i am using the Testing account for tool planner because of which this sort of result or dummy data is shown once the developer token approved the api will return the actual data.

Please see the adwords api forum discussion and the response/reply from the experts. [Please check](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adwords-api/Ezw0AH6XJeI/GtFu8ADBCgAJ;context-place=forum/adwords-api)